# First nested child element using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a list of recipes, and I want to grab the first item of one of the child elements:

```
<RECIPE>
   <NAME>Recipe1</NAME>
   <TYPE>Pasta</TYPE>
      <STEPS>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Boil</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>100C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Fry</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>150C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
      </STEPS>
</RECIPE>
```

I'm currently iterating over this and grabbing most of the data, but I'd like to be able to pull the temperature from the FIRST recipe step of EACH of the recipes I'm iterating to with the node loop.

I've got this working so far, but I think there must be a more elegant way using the find tools in ElementTree.

This is part of a function that is extracting a bunch of data into a Pandas data frame, the code looks a bit like what I posted above, I'll give you a bit more:

```
def import_XML(xml_file, df_cols):

    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()

    # df_cols = ["recipe_name", "version"]

    rows = []

    for node in xroot:
        s_recipe = node.attrib.get("RECIPE")
        recipe_name = node.find("NAME").text if node is not None else None
        version = node.find("VERSION").text if node is not None else None

        for steps in node.iter("STEP"):
            temperature = 
            round(float(steps.find("TEMPERATURE").text), 2)
            break

        rows.append({"recipe_name": recipe_name, "version": version, "temperature": temperature})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

This works but it pulls the last temperature from each recipe:

```
for steps in node.findall('STEPS'):
    temperature = steps.find('TEMPERATURE').text
```

I've tried a search like the following: `temperature = node.find(".//STEPS/STEP/TEMPERATURE").text` but it returns null.

Any more elegant solutions to this problem than breaking the loop folks?

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT updated for clarity - I want a list of the FIRST TEMPERATURES of EACH recipe]

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case you are looking only for the tempreature in the first step, this should do it:

```
print(xroot.find('.//STEPS/STEP[1]/TEMPERATURE').text)
```

Output:

```
'100C'
```

EDIT:

Assuming your html looks like this:

```
<recipes>
 <RECIPE>
   <NAME>Recipe1</NAME>
   <TYPE>Pasta</TYPE>
      <STEPS>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Boil</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>100C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Fry</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>150C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
      </STEPS>
</RECIPE>
<RECIPE>
   <NAME>Recipe2</NAME>
   <TYPE>Burger</TYPE>
      <STEPS>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Grill</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>250C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
         <STEP>
            <NAME>Serve</NAME>
            <TEMPERATURE>20C</TEMPERATURE>
         </STEP>
      </STEPS>
</RECIPE>
</recipes>
```

then

```
for temp in xroot.findall('.//RECIPE//STEPS/STEP[1]/TEMPERATURE'):
    print(temp.text)
```

should ouput:

```
100C
250C
```

Comment: probably should have made it clearer - I'd like to loop through the recipes and add the first temperature step in each recipe to a variable in the node loop. I think your code grabs the first one only if I'm not wrong. So at the end, I'd like a list of the first temperatures from EACH recipe.

Comment: thanks for the update. So trying to strike a balance between KISS and giving enough info for the question to be answered correctly, I probably missed out some important details.

Comment: I've added some more code from the Python function that hopefully makes things a bit more clearer. If I'm not wrong here, adding an extra loop here would make the function even more complex as I'd have to add the extra data to the frame separately, better to do it inside the main loop.

Comment: @jt196 I'm afraid I still don't understand what you want...

Comment: thanks for the help, sorry I've not been able to explain it properly. Getting terminology right is super important, but when you're starting out it's not easy to know what to ask for! 

Was looking to replace the `for steps in node.iter("STEP"):` loop with something a bit cleaner (instead of breaking), but inside the `for node in xroot:` loop. It's working fine as it is, just not very pretty code. I wasn't able to get your loop working inside the first loop as I think it's just looping through the xroot - and won't work looping through the node as above.